# Distribute In-house Apps fail to download with 3G/4G but wifi

Tags: ios, wifi, enterprise, 3g, 4g

When I try to distribute my in-house Apps. I put my Apps and download Html page in Dropbox. But When I download by 3G/4G online, it always fail and show "Unable to Download App", but when I turn to **use wifi to download, its works**! Is anyone know why?[image]

Comment: Is your app very large (e.g. over 100 MB) in size?  If so, Apple [won't allow you to download it via cellular data](http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/18/apple-raises-app-store-downloads-over-cellular-limit-to-100mb-per-app/).

Comment: NO, it's just about 25MB.

Comment: I suspect that the link points to a location in your internal network instead of a publicly exposed URL on the internet. What's the URL in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find my problem where is: I close "App Store" in Cellular to use cellular data.
I don't know why I distributed my App with enterprise program still need to use App Store?

anyway, if anyone have this problem next time, Settings > Cellular > USE CELLULAR DATA FOR > turn on "App Store".